# Proper CSS for fixed table layout in IE8 with colspan

Tags: html, html-table, internet-explorer-8

This is an excert from a dynamically built table.  What is the proper CSS to make the first `<td>` in the second rwo (id='backdate') a fixed width? *(currently it does not change width when increasing or decreasing the 70 value)*

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table class='fifo' width='850' style='width:850px;table-layout:fixed;'>
  <thead><tr>
   <th colspan='3' style='width:820px;'>Details</th>
   <th style='cursor:pointer;width:15px;' title='Click to save.'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-check'/></th>
   <th style='width:15px;' title='Click to close.'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-closethick'/></th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr><td id='BACKDATE' colspan='1' class='button' style='cursor:pointer;width:70px;' width='70' title='Back Date Start Date/time.'>Back Date</td>
   <td colspan='4' style='width:780px;' width='780'><b>Start Date: </b></td></tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

[FIDDLE WITH SOLUTION...](http://jsbin.com/okekal/13/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a dummy row with the widths that the browser 'displays', but isn't seen solves the problem. To get rid of the extra border, I had to add `border-top-width:0px;` to the table's `style`.

***HTML***

```
<tr>
  <th class='test' style='width:80px;'/>
  <th class='test' style='width:560px;'/>
  <th class='test' style='width:150px;'/>
  <th class='test' style='width:15px;'/>
  <th class='test' style='width:15px;'/>
```

***CSS***

```
.test {
  padding:0px!important;
  border-width:0px!important;
  height:0px!important;
}
```